# Date filter that is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, date, ionic-framework

I have an application that I test at the moment, everything works perfectly apart from a part.

The date filter works only once every two.
I check on Postman and the BDD, the date is correct, but I do not understand why instead of displaying the date it show me "null".

Here is a screenshot and my code:[image]

my view :

```
<ion-list id="ficheJeune-list10">
  <ion-item id="ficheJeune-list-item22" ng-repeat="element in patient.cr track by $index" ng-click="showDescr(patient.id, element)">
    <div class="col col-sm-50">Compte Rendu du :</div>
    <div class="col col-sm-50 date">{{ element.date | dateOnly: "dd MMMM y" }}</div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

my filter :

```
.filter('dateOnly', [
'$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(input, format) {
        return $filter('date')(new Date(input), format);
    };
}
    ])
```

mon json :

```
{
"id": 50,
"prenom": "Jonathan",
"cr": [
    {
        "date": "12 mars 2010",
        "lieu": test
    },
    {
        "date": "05 mars 2010",
        "lieu": test
    },
    {
        "date": "04 mai 2006",
        "lieu": test
    },
    {
        "date": "27 avril 2006",
        "lieu": test
    },
    {
        "date": "14 avril 2006",
        "lieu": test
    },
    {
        "date": "07 avril 2006",
        "lieu": test
    },
    {
        "date": "23 mars 2006",
        "lieu": test
    },
    {
        "date": "16 mars 2006",
        "lieu": test
    }
]
}
```

I searched all day what could cause this but I can not find ..

I thank you in advance

Comment: please post JSON data

Comment: I edited my question to put the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write custom map that converts month name from french to english.

In your case `mai` and `avril` fails.

<kbd>[Demo represents the issue](https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/prOYqv?editors=1010)</kbd>

```
.filter('dateOnly', [
'$filter', function($filter) {

  var mappingMonth = {
    "avril": "april",
    "mars": "march",
    "mai" : "may"    
  }; // and so on

    return function(input, format) {

        input = input.split(" ")[0] + " " + mappingMonth[input.split(" ")[1]] + " " + input.split(" ")[2]

        return $filter('date')(new Date(input), format);
      };
     }
   ])
```

<kbd>[Fixed demo](https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/JyazVr?editors=1010)</kbd>

Comment: Okay, I understand what's going on for those months.
But I do not understand why it does not for other months ^^

Comment: @MaximShoustin  thank you for the answer ;)
I would also like to understand why it works sometimes and sometimes not?

Comment: @DaxDev date format parsing is based on ISO 8601 so looks like some glitch

Answer (score 0):

It is because your date format is wrong. for example change to `mai` to `may`.
see demo in flowing:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
    $scope.data = {
"id": 50,
"prenom": "Jonathan",
"cr": [
    {
        "date": "12 mars 2010",
     "lieu": "test"
    },
    {
        "date": "05 mars 2010",
        "lieu": "test"
    },
    {
        "date": "04 may 2006",
         "lieu": "test"
    },
    {
        "date": "27 apr 2006",
        "lieu": "test"
    },
    {
        "date": "14 aprww 2006",
        "lieu": "test"
    },
    {
        "date": "07 apr 2006",
         "lieu": "test"
    },
    {
        "date": "23 mars 2006",
        "lieu": "test"
    },
    {
        "date": "16 mars 2006",
         "lieu": "test"
    }
]
}
});
app.filter('dateOnly', [
'$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(input, format) {
        return $filter('date')(new Date(input), format);
    };
}
    ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">
  <div id="ficheJeune-list-item22" ng-repeat="element in data.cr">
    <div class="col col-sm-50 date">{{ element.date | dateOnly: "dd MMMM y" }} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I understand what's going on for those months.
But I do not understand why it does not for other months ^^

Comment: date format for month only take first 3 character and other month is only `mars` here. so that take the first three letters that for `mars` is `mar` and it is correct for format.for example i change `apr` to `aprww` but it's woks correctly still.